# How to get initials easily out of text field using Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using Postgres version 9.4 and I have a `full_name` field in a table.

In some cases, I want to put initials instead  of the full_name of the person in my table.

Something like:

```
Name        | Initials
------------------------
Joe Blow    | J. B.  
Phil Smith  | P. S.
```

The `full_name` field is a string value (obviously) and I think the best way to go about this is to split the string into an array foreach space i.e.:

```
select full_name, string_to_array(full_name,' ') initials
from my_table
```

This produces the following result-set:

```
Eric A. Korver;{Eric,A.,Korver}
Ignacio Bueno;{Ignacio,Bueno}
Igmar Mendoza;{Igmar,Mendoza}
```

Now, the only thing I am missing is how to loop through each array element and pull the 1st character out of it. I will end up using `substring()` to get the initial character of each element - however I am just stuck on how to loop through them on-the-fly..

Anybody have a simple way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unnest` with `string_agg`:

```
select full_name, string_agg(substr(initials, 1,1)||'.', ' ') initials
from (
    select full_name, unnest(string_to_array(full_name,' ')) initials
    from my_table
    ) sub
group by 1;

       full_name        |  initials   
------------------------+-------------
 Phil Smith             | P. S.
 Joe Blow               | J. B.
 Jose Maria Allan Pride | J. M. A. P.
 Eric A. Korver         | E. A. K.
(4 rows)
```

In Postgres 14+ you can replace `unnest(string_to_array(...))` with `string_to_table(...)`.

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/YDYto5uY)

Answer (score 1):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aa6f9/7)**

```
WITH add_id AS (
     SELECT n.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Name") AS id
     FROM names n
),
split_names AS (
     SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table("Name", E'\\s+') AS single_name
     FROM add_id
),
initials AS (
      SELECT id, left(single_name, 1) || '.' AS initial
      FROM split_names
),
final AS (
      SELECT id, string_agg(initial, ' ')
      FROM initials
      GROUP BY id
) 
SELECT a.*, f.*
FROM add_id a
JOIN final f USING (id)
```

For debug I create the `Initial` to Show how match the `string_agg`

```
|           Name | Initials | id | id | string_agg |
|----------------|----------|----|----|------------|
| Eric A. Korver | E. A. K. |  1 |  1 |   E. A. K. |
|  Igmar Mendoza |    I. M. |  2 |  2 |      I. M. |
|  Ignacio Bueno |    I. B. |  3 |  3 |      I. B. |
|       Joe Blow |    J. B. |  4 |  4 |      J. B. |
|     Phil Smith |    P. S. |  5 |  5 |      P. S. |
```

After some work I got a compact version [**SqlFiddleDemo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aa6f9/14)

```
  SELECT "Name", string_agg(left(single_name, 1) || '.', '') AS Initials
  FROM (
        SELECT
          "Name",
          regexp_split_to_table("Name", E'\\s+') AS single_name
        FROM names
       ) split_names
  GROUP BY "Name"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|           Name | initials |
|----------------|----------|
| Eric A. Korver |   E.K.A. |
|  Igmar Mendoza |     M.I. |
|  Ignacio Bueno |     I.B. |
|       Joe Blow |     B.J. |
|     Phil Smith |     P.S. |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a helper function for this, in case you want to use similar logic in multiple queries. Check this out

```
--
-- Function to extract a person's initials from the full name.
--

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_name_initials(TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name_initials(full_name TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE 
    result TEXT :='';
    part VARCHAR :='';
BEGIN
    FOREACH part IN ARRAY string_to_array($1, ' ') LOOP
        result :=  result || substr(part, 1, 1) || '.';
    END LOOP;

    RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now you can simply use this `function` to get the initials like this.

```
SELECT full_name, get_name_initials(full_name) as initials
FROM my_table;

SELECT get_name_initials('Phil Smith'); -- Returns P. H. 
SELECT get_name_initials('Joe Blow'); -- Returns J. B.
```