# Using Postgres `unnest` and `substr` together in Django 2.2

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I am trying to write a Django annotation to add initials generated from words in a single CharField in a Django model. For example:

- `The ABC Company` would become `TAC`
- `A Company Making Everything` would become `ACME`

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.2. I found the following SQL from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312435/3443946:

```sql
select name, string_agg(substr(initials, 1,1)||'.', ' ') initials
from (
  select name, unnest(string_to_array(full_name,' ')) initials
  from app_model
) sub group by 1;
```

This SQL works (more or less), and now I'm trying to adapt it to Django. I implemented StringToArray based off of https://brownbears.tistory.com/496 (adapted slightly to remove an internal variable reference and a possible translation error):

```py
class StringToArray(Func):
  function = 'string_to_array'
  output_field = ArrayField(CharField(max_length=1))
  arity = 1
  template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s,'%(delimiter)s','%(null)s')"

  def __init__(self, expression, delimiter=',', null=''):
    super().__init__(expression, delimiter=delimiter, null=null)
```

Unnest seems pretty easy as the following:

```py
class Unnest(Func):
  function = 'unnest'
```

I implemented the two commands above like this:

```py
Account.objects.annotate(
  unnested_strings=Unnest(
    StringToArray(
      F('name'), delimiter=' '
    )
  )
).values()
```

The above correctly returns the following queryset (shown as a dict for simplicity):

```py
[
  {
    'name': 'The ABC Company',
    'unnested_strings': 'The',
    ...
  },
  {
    'name': 'The ABC Company',
    'unnested_strings': 'ABC',
    ...
  },
  {
    'name': 'The ABC Company',
    'unnested_strings': 'Company',
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

That works fine, so here's my attempt at implementing the rest of it with `Substr` and `StringAgg`:

```py
Account.objects.annotate(
  initials=StringAgg(
    Substr(
      StringToArray(
        F('name'), delimiter=' '
      ), 1, 1
    ), delimiter=''
  )
).values()
```

When I run the above, I get the following `psycopg2` error:

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
LINE 1: ...T "accounts_account"."name", STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(unnest(str...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

From the error message, it looks like `Substr` doesn't work directly on `Unnest` results, which is why the original SQL had a `group by` clause before using `Substr`. However, I'm not very clear on how to do that in Django. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good way to do this with just pure ORM-based database calls. Rather than messing with raw SQL, I ended up making this a non-required field on the model that's automatically populated on model save:

```py
# models.py

def get_initials(text):
  return ''.join([_[0] for _ in text.split(' ') if _])
class Account(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  initials = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

  def save(self, update_fields=None, *args, **kwargs):
    initials = get_initials(self.name)
    if self.initials != initials:
      self.initials = initials

      # skip update_fields if this is a new object
      # ._state is actually public, just named that way to prevent conflicts
      if not self._state.adding:
        if update_fields:
          update_fields.append('initials')
        else:
          update_fields = ['initials']

    super().save(update_fields=update_fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

The added `update_fields` logic isn't strictly necessary, but I use that parameter in my Django signals to tell what has changed in an updated model.